# Deploying a lambda with terraform that contains multiple files?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I have a python lambda I want to deploy that depends on some other python scripts. The lambda itself can't run without those. Looking at the docs, I don't see a way for me to process that entire "folder" as lambda and deploy it that way. I understand I can easily add that specific lambda in my step function later, but I need other scripts to go with it so I could actually run it. I know how to use archive provider to archive the entire folder, could that be helpful in my efforts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Terraform [archive provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file) to create a zip of the entire folder. Then reference the zip file as your Lambda function source.